# How to skip a callback in a dependent model on destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have providers and positions. When the provider is destroyed, I need to destroy any positions. However, my `check_primary` method, in `position.rb` is crashing when I try and destroy a provider.

**provider.rb**

```
  has_many :positions, dependent: :destroy
```

**position.rb**

```
  after_destroy :check_primary

  def check_primary
    unless provider.primary_position # this shouldn't run when destroying a provider
      if provider.positions.present?
        provider.positions.first.update_column(:primary, true) # crash here
      end
    end
  end
```

Error on provider destroy: **cannot update a destroyed record**

**My Question**

I would like to put a skip_callback in `provider.rb` which skips `check_primary` in `position.rb` whenever the `provider.destroy` method is called. **How can I accomplish this?**

When analyzing the parent object with pry from within `:check_primary` I see:

```
>> provider.destroyed?
=> false
>> provider.frozen?
=> false
>> provider.marked_for_destruction?
=> false
```

**UPDATE**

I can't figure this out for now... So here's a really bad workaround:

```
  def check_primary
    unless provider.primary_position
      begin
        provider.positions.first.update_column(:primary, true)
      rescue
        nil
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try skipping it in the context of destroy. In position.rb:

```
skip_callback :check_primary, on: destroy
```

EDIT to resolve my misunderstanding. I had more confidence in my original, off-point answer but I believe you can simply pass it a condition as follows:

```
skip_callback :check_primary, if: -> { #conditions }
```

Comment: Sorry some background: I am calling this method when destroying a position to ensure that a primary position is assigned if the user deletes their primary.

Comment: Ah--I see the after_destroy, now. I needed to read more carefully.

Comment: Please leave your answer up as it may help others. Thanks.

Comment: So now I am trying `after_destroy :check_primary, unless: -> { conditions }` but I honestly have no idea what to put for the conditions since provider.destroyed? evaluates to false.

Comment: I see. Tough to help with the condition without having a better understanding. Could you assign a different primary `before_destroy`? That way you'd still have access to the object.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Rails has a callback for this:  `after_remove`, which in this case would be used like (in Provider.rb) -

```
  has_many :positions, dependent: :destroy, after_remove: :check_primary
```

and then move `check_primary` into the Provider model and modify it to act from within that class rather than the Position class.